# Paypal Sandbox SSL Issue & Redirect Issue

Tags: paypal

I am attempting to use Paypal Sandbox for testing and making payments with Paypal on a test copy of my website. It appears to have stopped working correctly and I haven't made any changes my end so it looks like the issue is on Paypal's end.

If I click on a pay/buy now button for example, it takes me to Paypal where it offers me to create a paypal account or pay login with Paypal.

If I chose to login with Paypal by clicking "Log in" on the image below:

[image: Log In]

I am met with a warning in Chrome as you can see below, their certificate hasn't expired (expires in September 2017) so I am not really sure what `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` means.

[image: Warning]

If I tell chrome to proceed anyway it allows me to view a generic login screen:

[image: Login]

However after logging in doesn't redirect me back to my website, nor does it even ask to confirm payment instead it just takes me to  "My account" for that test Paypal account.

If I look at the "Complete payments" there is a correct £5 payment but it's listed as a pre-approved payment and isn't sending an IPN notification to my website.

Not sure what is going wrong... anyone have any advice?

Comment: Still having the exact same issue. Found a work-around yet?

Comment: Still nothing, Paypal are being pretty useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal have fixed the issue for payments & redirects, as for the SSL warning for now just Click "Advanced" and then "Proceed to sandbox3.paypal.com"